selecting multiple pods with similar prefixes but different siffixes
I installed Prometheus using Helm, which automatically includes cAdvisor and other components. I have several pods with similar names, but each has a unique identifier, such as my-app-23hj2 and my-app-44h23.
I created a Grafana dashboard to visualize resource utilization for these pods, and I want to select all pods that start with the prefix my-app. However, I can't use my-app.* because I have other pods with different names like url-shortener-2u3j2, so I cannot directly use the regex my-app.*.
- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
  regex: "^([^-]+)-.*"
  target_label: first_word
  replacement: $1

I tried creating new labels using regex to capture only the first two suffixes of each pod name, but I haven't gotten it right. How can I correctly filter these pods by their common prefix?

Do you want to filter on pod labels instead?

You can filter pods begining with my-app substring directly in Grafana using pattern pod=~"my-app-[^-]+". For example:
sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{pod=~"my-app-[^-]+"}) 


thank you very much for the reply, but I have multiple pods with different suffixes, so I am not looking to query just one, the query will be used in a dashboard and when I click on a single pod, I want all pod with similar suffixes to be selected.
